# Setting up a VPN client connection in CentOS 7

Tags: windows, centos, vpn, centos7, pptp

I have to connect remotely from client on `CentOS` to `VPN` server, hosted on `Windows`.

What have been done:

1. Installed packages **yum install ppp pptp**
2. Contents of **/etc/ppp/peers/harkiv_vpn**

   ```
   # pty "pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd" # using IP address
   pty "pptp vpn.campus.harkiv.ua --nolaunchpppd"
   lock
   noauth
   nobsdcomp
   nodeflate
   nodefaultroute
   usepeerdns
   name user_name
   remotename harkiv_vpn
   ipparam harkiv_vpn
   refuse-pap
   refuse-eap
   refuse-chap
   refuse-mschap
   require-mppe
   nomppe-stateful
   ```
3. Contents of  **/etc/ppp/chap-secrets**

   ```
   # Secrets for authentication using CHAP
   # client server secret IP addresses

   user_name harkiv_vpn "user_password_in_dblquotes" *
   ```
4. Created script **start_vpn1.sh**

   ```
   systemctl stop firewalld            # stop the firewall
   pppd call harkiv_vpn                # start VPN connection
   # pppd call megarvpn debug nodetach # for starting VPN manually
   ```
5. Created script **stop_vpn.sh**

   ```
   pkill pptp                # stop VPN connection
   systemctl start firewalld # start the firewall
   systemctl restart network # restarting service recreates the file resolv.conf
   ```

---

After all that `vpn` connection starts, but I still can't access remote resources. What have I missed?

Comment: Warning: PPTP is obsolete and insecure. It does not provide privacy or confidentiality and should not be used if you need these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running script **start_vpn1.sh**, the VPN connection is started, but the gateway in it is taken from the current network connection, not from a remote VPN server. To correct this:

6. Contents of **/etc/resolv.conf**

   ```
   # Generated by NetworkManager
   search harkiv.local
   nameserver zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz # Remote VPN server gateway <- add this line
   nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # DNS1 of network connection
   nameserver yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy # DNS2 of network connection
   ```
7. Create script **start_vpn2.sh**

   ```
   cp resolv.conf /etc/
   route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
   ```